# Session timeout in mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, session-timeout, session-management

How should I use the tag  in the web.config in my MVC4 application, framework 4.0?

I added it in the web config like this:

```
<sessionState timeout="15"  />
```

but it didn't time out.

Also I can't understand for certain what it means if I set mode="StateServer" or mode="InProc"
In the msdn it say about "InProc" - "Session state is in process with an ASP.NET worker process."
But I don't know how to understand it and which one to choose.

Thank you.

Comment: How did you determine it doesn't time out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

configure it in the web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx"
        loginUrl="~/Login.aspx"
        slidingExpiration="true"
        timeout="60" />
</authentication>
```

With the configuration above, the user will be always redirected to the Login.aspx page when their session expires. There is a timeout of 60 minutes, and sliding expiration means that the timeout is extended each time the user makes a request to the web application, so if he stays active the session will not expire. A configuration like this gives you another advantage over what you tried to do - once the user logs in he will be automatically redirected back to the resource he originally requested. And you can always override and customize this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [this session timeout post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9385744/1558859) to clarify how the timeout works and why it may not have for you.

Regarding what the different modes mean you can visit [Session-State Modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I already know the stuff you showed me. So maybe I am not askign my question correctly.